# +1 on non-Google sites - is a plus account mandatory to vote?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I couldn't find this info anywhere.
In order to give a +1 (and increase the counter), the person who votes **must** have a google account.

But the question is. Is it enough for the voter to have let's say, a gmail account, or the vote will be registered only if the voter has a google plus account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a public Google profile to use the +1 button. At this time, the only way to create a public Google profile is to upgrade to Google+. Some users with legacy public profiles can use the +1 button without upgrading to Google+.

From the [FAQ](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1047397&topic=1207011&ctx=topic):

> In order to use the Google +1 button, you need to have a public Google
>   Profile visible to the world, which at a minimum includes the name you
>   chose for the profile.